# Display a column of data in a new column, using column heading

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu, excel-formula

I am trying to create a callable column of data in Excel, based on a dropdown list.

The idea is to create a list of all column names in a header cell at the end of the columns, using Data Validation from the Data Menu in Excel.

[image]

Then, when you select the column name from the list, the entire column is populated with the column values from the name that you have referenced.

It should look like this.

[image]

This is easy enough to do with IF statements when there are only a handful of columns to call.  When there are hundreds of columns you want to be able to reference. The IF statements method means you will have to write hundreds of IF statements.

Is there a way to do this with VBA or otherwise for many columns?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you want to do now, but this would be an Idea how to store your values or just copy them strait from another place in your worksheets

```
Sub Test()

    Dim Column_1 As Variant

        Column_1 = Range("B1:B500")
    'You could use "Column_1" to get your values whereever you need 
End Sub

Sub Test_2()
    If Sheets("OneOfYourSheets").Range("B1") = Sheets("OneOfYourSheets").Range("xyz1") Then
        Sheets("OneOfYourSheets").Range("B2:B501") = Sheets("OneOfYourSheets").Range("xyz2:xyz501")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Will this data be called when the dropdown list selects that column name though?

Comment: The data I'm trying to select from the drop down menu is grabbed from other columns in  the sheet like so...

=IF($F$1=$A$1,$A2,IF($F$1=$B$1,$B2,IF($F$1=$C$1,$C2,IF($F$1=$D$1,$D2,))))

Answer (score 0):

This is a textbook case for `INDEX`/`MATCH`.

In `F2`, enter this formula: `=INDEX(A:D,ROW(),MATCH(F$1,$A$1:$D$1,0))`, where `ROW()` gives you the row number and `MATCH` gives you the column number.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you.